# Getting duplicate metrics when doing querying from the Prometheus Server

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, metrics, autoscaling, kube-state-metrics

I am getting metrics exposed by kube-state-metrics by querying Prometheus-server but the issue is I am getting duplicate metrics with difference only in the job field. . I am doing query such as :

```
curl 'http://10.101.202.25:80/api/v1/query?query=kube_pod_status_phase'| jq
```

The only difference is coming the job field. [Metrics coming when querying Prometheus-Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHXJW.jpg)

All pods running in the cluster: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxNXz.jpg

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

**prometheus.yml**

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

rule_files:
  # - "first.rules"
  # - "second.rules"

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

Comment: Could you share your Prometheus configuration? (prometheus.yaml)

Comment: @SYN I am making use of value.yml file that is present here : https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml.

Comment: @SYN I have added the prometheus.yml file in the post.

Answer (score 1):

You are running (or at least ingesting) two copies of kube-state-metrics. Probably one you installed and configured yourself and another from something like kube-prometheus-stack?

Comment: I had only 1 instance of the prometheus-kube-state-metrics which comes by default with prometheus when setting it up through the helm charts. 
But I am now getting the appropriate 1 type of metrics only. 
What I did was removing the scrap config of prometheus-kube-state-metrics from the value.yml and defining that in the config file i.e. prometheus.yml. For now it's working fine.

Comment: It doesn't come with Prometheus, you installed it via Helm from the looks of thing. The only thing that comes with Prometheus is Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I wanted eventually. What I did was to remove the scraping config of prometheus-kube-state-metrics from the value.yml and defining that in the config file i.e. prometheus.yml. For now it's working fine. Thank You @SYN and @coderanger for the help.